# hide and show combobox base another combobox value in Nintex of sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, sharepoint-online, nintex-workflow

Im new in Sharepoint

i have combobox name `c_RequestType` with value `value1 & value2`
and another combobox name `c_GuaranteeType` in nintex workflow

when changing value of `c_RequestType` the `c_GuaranteeType` should be hide or show

I found this in net

> If(c_RequestType.Selected.Value = "value1", true, false)

and doesn't work find some script but nothing

thanx for your helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the code thanx by me :))

```
form.GetControl("c_RequestType").GetValue() == "value1" && form.ViewMode() == false
```